# How prove this $\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t}$ and the matrix $C$？

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

**Aussme that Vector group**
$\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t}$can By linearly independent group
$a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{s}$Linear expression
,meaning that 
$$(\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t})=(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{s})C_{s\times t}$$
show that :$\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t}$and the matrix $C$ The column vectors have the same linear relationship

My  try:

> let
>   $$\beta_{1}=c_{11}a_{1}+c_{12}a_{2}+\cdots+c_{1s}a_{s}$$
>   $$\beta_{2}=c_{21}a_{1}+c_{22}a_{2}+\cdots+c_{2s}a_{s}$$
>   $$\cdots\cdots\cdots$$
>   $$\beta_{t}=c_{t1}a_{1}+c_{t2}a_{2}+\cdots+c_{ts}a_{s}$$

sorry,I guess you can't  understand my problme mean?

**The chinese  language
problem：**
  设向量组$\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t}$可由线性无关的向量组$\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{s}$线性表出,且我们记为
$$(\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t})=(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{s})C_{s\times t}$$
证明:$\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\cdots,\beta_{t}$和矩阵$C$的列向量组有相同的线性关系

**I hope someone can help me.Thank you  very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very unclear, but I think you might be asking why, if the $1\times t$-matrix $b=(\beta_1~\ldots~\beta_t)$ is a linear combination of the rows of the $s\times t$-matrix$~C$ (so $b=a\cdot C$), it is that every linear relation satisfied by the columns of$~C$ is also satisfied by the entries of$~b$.

This is simply because such a linear relation, say with coeffcients $d_1,\ldots,d_t$ means that $C\cdot d=\vec0$ where $d$ is a $t\times1$-matrix with entries $d_1,\ldots,d_t$. Then $b\cdot d=a\cdot C\cdot d=a\cdot\vec0=0$.

Comment: Than you ,why $b\cdot d=a\cdot C\cdot d?$

Comment: Because the question says that $b=a\cdot C$ (and matrix multplication is associative so you may omit parentheses).